# SQL Server join query returning duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

```
WITH JC AS -- Job Card
(   
    SELECT DISTINCT(JOBCARDNOSTR),
        'Job Card' AS Document, 
        JobCardId, 
        COUNT(*) Count 
    FROM 
        JobCardMaster 
    WHERE
        (JobCardId = 50075) 
    GROUP BY
        JobCardId, JOBCARDNOSTR
),
PR AS   -- Purchase Request
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(PurchaseRequestNo),
        'Purchase Request' AS Document, 
        JobCardId, 
        COUNT(*) Count 
    FROM
        PurchaseRequestMaster 
    WHERE
        (JobCardId = 50075) 
    GROUP BY 
        JobCardId, PurchaseRequestNo
),
ENQ AS ---- Enquiry
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(enquiryno),
        'Enquiry' AS Document, 
        JobCardId, 
        COUNT(*) Count 
    FROM
        EnquiryMaster 
    WHERE
        (JobCardId = 50075) 
    GROUP BY 
        JobCardId, enquiryno
),
CMPRTV AS ---- Comparative
(
    SELECT DISTINCT(ComparativeNo),
        'Comparative' AS Document, 
        JobCardId,
        COUNT(*) Count 
    FROM
        ComparativeMaster 
    WHERE
        (JobCardId = 50075) 
    GROUP BY 
        JobCardId, ComparativeNo
),
PO SA ---- Purchase Order 
    (
        select 'Purchase Order' as Document, JobCardId, poorderno,count(*) Count from PurchaseOrderMaster where (JobCardId = 50075 ) group by JobCardId,poorderno
    ),
    GRN as ---- GRN
    (
        Select distinct(GrnGinNo),'GRN' as Document, JobCardId, count(*) Count from Gin where (JobCardId = 50075 ) group by JobCardId,GrnGinNo
    ),
    TI as ---- Tax Invoice
    (
        Select distinct(GrnExInvno),'Tax Invoice' as Document, JobCardId, count(*) Count from Gin where (JobCardId = 50075 ) group by JobCardId,GrnExInvno
    ),
    DC as -- DC
    (
        Select distinct(dcrefno),'DC' as Document, JobCardId,count(*) Count from DCMaster where (JobCardId = 50075 ) group by JobCardId,dcrefno
    )
    select  
    ISNULL(JC.Count,0) as JCrdCount, JC.JOBCARDNOSTR,ISNULL(PR.Count,0) as PRCount, pr.PurchaseRequestNo
    ,ENQ.enquiryno, ISNULL(ENQ.Count,0) as ENQCount
    ,CMPRTV.ComparativeNo, ISNULL(CMPRTV.Count,0) as CMPRTVCount
    , PO.poorderno,ISNULL(PO.Count,0) as POCount, 
    GRN.GrnGinNo,ISNULL(GRN.Count,0) as GRNCount
    
    , TI.GrnExInvno,ISNULL(TI.Count,0) as TICount,
    DC.dcrefno,ISNULL(DC.Count,0) as DCCount
    FROM JC
     --JCrd 
    left JOIN PR ON JC.JobCardId = PR.JobCardId 
    left JOIN ENQ ON JC.JobCardId = ENQ.JobCardId
    left JOIN CMPRTV ON JC.JobCardId = CMPRTV.JobCardId
    left JOIN PO ON JC.JobCardId = PO.JobCardId 
    left JOIN GRN ON JC.JobCardId = GRN.JobCardId
    left JOIN TI ON JC.JobCardId = TI.JobCardId
    left JOIN DC ON JC.JobCardId = DC.JobCardId
    order by JC.JobCardId desc
```

Comment: Just dumping some code into a question does not make a question. As a user for over a year, you are yet to take the [tour]; I strongly recommend you do, as it is clear you don't understand the site.

Answer (score 1):

**`distinct` is not a function.** It doesn't mean "distinct on the value immediately following in brackets (somevalue)", it just means "distinct over **all** columns (some of which can be in brackets)".

So if you want only one row per `JobCardId` in each of those subqueries, then group only by that. And use aggregation such as `MIN` or `MAX` for the other columns.

it's a little bit strange that you only have the `where JobCardId = 50075` filter in the subqueries and not on the outside. If you are doing that for performance then you are wasting your time: the compiler is fully capable of pushing filters through subqueries even with `GROUP BY`.

```sql
WITH JC as
    -- Job Card
    (
        select
            MIN(JOBCARDNOSTR) AS JOBCARDNOSTR,
            'Job Card' as Document,
            JobCardId,
            count(*) Count
        from JobCardMaster
        where JobCardId = 50075
        group by JobCardId
    ),
    PR as
    -- Purchase Request
    (
        select
            MIN(PurchaseRequestNo) AS PurchaseRequestNo,
            'Purchase Request' as Document,
            JobCardId, count(*) Count
        from PurchaseRequestMaster
        where JobCardId = 50075
        group by JobCardId
    ),
    ENQ as
    ---- Enquiry
    (
        select
          MIN(enquiryno) AS enquiryno,
          'Enquiry' as Document,
          JobCardId,
          count(*) Count
        from EnquiryMaster
        where JobCardId = 50075
        group by JobCardId
    ),
    CMPRTV as
    ---- Comparative
    (
        select
          MIN(ComparativeNo) AS ComparativeNo,
          'Comparative' as Document,
          JobCardId,
          count(*) Count
        from ComparativeMaster
        where JobCardId = 50075
        group by JobCardId
    ),
    PO as
    ---- Purchase Order 
    (
        select
          'Purchase Order' as Document,
          JobCardId,
          MIN(poorderno) AS poorderno,
          count(*) Count
        from PurchaseOrderMaster
        where JobCardId = 50075
        group by JobCardId
    ),
    GRN as
    ---- GRN
    (
        Select
          MIN(GrnGinNo),
         'GRN' as Document,
         JobCardId,
         count(*) Count
        from Gin
        where JobCardId = 50075
        group by JobCardId
    ),
    TI as
    ---- Tax Invoice
    (
        Select
          MIN(GrnExInvno) AS GrnExInvno,
          'Tax Invoice' as Document,
          JobCardId,
          count(*) Count
        from Gin
        where JobCardId = 50075
        group by JobCardId
    ),
    DC as
    -- DC
    (
        Select
          MIN(dcrefno) AS dcrefno,
          'DC' as Document,
          JobCardId,
          count(*) Count
        from DCMaster
        where JobCardId = 50075
        group by JobCardId
    )
select
    ISNULL(JC.Count,0) as JCrdCount,
    JC.JOBCARDNOSTR,
    ISNULL(PR.Count,0) as PRCount,
    pr.PurchaseRequestNo,
    ENQ.enquiryno,
    ISNULL(ENQ.Count,0) as ENQCount,
    CMPRTV.ComparativeNo,
    ISNULL(CMPRTV.Count,0) as CMPRTVCount,
    PO.poorderno,
    ISNULL(PO.Count,0) as POCount,
    GRN.GrnGinNo,
    ISNULL(GRN.Count,0) as GRNCount,    
    TI.GrnExInvno,
    ISNULL(TI.Count,0) as TICount,
    DC.dcrefno,
    ISNULL(DC.Count,0) as DCCount
FROM JC
    --JCrd 
    left JOIN PR ON JC.JobCardId = PR.JobCardId
    left JOIN ENQ ON JC.JobCardId = ENQ.JobCardId
    left JOIN CMPRTV ON JC.JobCardId = CMPRTV.JobCardId
    left JOIN PO ON JC.JobCardId = PO.JobCardId
    left JOIN GRN ON JC.JobCardId = GRN.JobCardId
    left JOIN TI ON JC.JobCardId = TI.JobCardId
    left JOIN DC ON JC.JobCardId = DC.JobCardId
order by
  JC.JobCardId desc;
```

Comment: here by using this  query now it gives 1 record.previously it was giving 64 records which is wrong. now it should give minimum 4 records .what to do?

Comment: Well you haven't given us any sample data or expected output so how would we know that? I have no idea what is right or wrong for your unwritten requirement, I'm just concentrating on "removing duplicates" which you mentioned. Perhaps you need to aggregate on two levels, but it's not clear. All you given is a code dump.